# Sort get_children by menu_order

Tags: get-posts, get-children, menu-order

I'm using the jQuery Carousel Gallery and unfortunately it's not working with WP's new v3.5 gallery ordering. When the client drags to rearrange images, those changes are not reflected in the front-end gallery. The plugin is no longer maintained, sadly. So I dove in and can see it's using `get_children`.

I see this:

```
$attachments = get_children(
    array(
        'post_parent' => $id,
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    )
);
```

And this:

```
$js = array();
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, "full");
    // $image = the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    $js[] = "{url: '" . $image[0] . "', title: '".addslashes($attachment->post_title)."', caption: '".addslashes(remove_brs($attachment->post_excerpt))."', description: '".addslashes(remove_brs($attachment->post_content))."'}";
}
$output .= join(",\n", $js);
$output .= "];\n";`
```

I've seen here and elsewhere that get_posts will adhere to the menu_order `orderby` parameter, so to try it out I gave this attempt:

```
$post_img_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' =>'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);
$attachments = get_posts($post_img_args);
```

And in the `foreach` statement above, I replaced the `$image` variable with

```
$image = the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
```

This destroyed the gallery on the front end. (A quick note that disabling the plugin and viewing on the front shows the image-ordering just fine, so I do believe it rests with the above code and what it outputs).

Any insight or guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `$id` of the first statement and the `$post->ID` of your second statement are the same?

Comment: Hi @fischi - I believe they are. `$ID` is coded before these statements, as `$id = intval($id);`.

Answer (score 1):

Following WordPress 3.5, gallery shortcodes now include the image IDs by default. Like this `[gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]` which also holds the order, so open the plugin file named `carousel-gallery-jquery.php` and replace this line: (around line 140)

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
```

with this:

```
if ( isset($include) && !empty($include) ) {
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
                $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
} elseif ( isset($exclude) && !empty($exclude) ) {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}
```

then at the top of that function on line 121 add this:

```
if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
    // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
    if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
            $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}
```

and you should be fine :)

Comment: you rock. Thanks so much. I'm still not getting the sort order on the front to reflect the changes from dragging in WP's gallery. Do I need to remove the `if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {...` which was in place originally? Also, anything to change with the shortcode extract? `extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'orderby'    => 'menu_order',
  'id'         => $post->ID,
  'itemtag'    => 'dl',
  'icontag'    => 'dt',
  'captiontag' => 'dd',
  'columns'    => 3,
  'size'       => 'thumbnail',
 ), $attr));
 
 $id = intval($id);`

Comment: Nothing more then I posted

Comment: Anyone else able to provide more insight on this? I have directly replaced $orderby with `'post__in'` in the suggested parameters array above, but this does not work either. The images still do not appear in the order of IDs in the WP editor.